# Embedded IE (COM application) in Java application

Tags: java, internet-explorer

As same as the title, is that possible to achieve this right now. Since I have already had application that works on web browser. I want to create a java version app which just simply load the URL and performs most of the functionality as the web browser.

I have tried to use JavaFx webEngine, it can show the content of the page, but it does not support upload or download. For simplicity reason, I do not wish to rewrite code to handle upload/download or even more duplicate stuffs in feature.

I have tried JDIC, but seems it is abandon project and I have got such error:

```
org.jdesktop.jdic.init.JdicInitException: java.lang.UnsatisfiedLinkError: no jdic in java.library.path
```

I do add the jdic.jar which I download from nowhere to the lib path.

I also tried this link (http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/514/Embed-ActiveX-controls-inside-Java-GUI), but it is from 10 years ago and some components have been remove from JDK.

Any help will be appreciated!

Comment: What version of Java/JavaFX are you using? I ask because the JavaFX webengine (or webview more precisely) does in fact support file upload.

Comment: @barry-johnson I am using j7u51 and javafx 2.0, I did not try upload but the download is not working on my side.

Comment: By download, you mean "save as" functionality I take it, since obviously it has to download content to render the page. My gut tells me that if this is the approach you want to take you will be better off making the tweaks to the webengine. Just my two cents, I'd contemplate some alternative approaches to your general goal of a desktop app as a frontend. Not sure that I would bother using Java to make a windows-only app (which is what you'd get with the IE embedding). If you generally want to run as a standalone app, you could work up an .hta file wrapper (win only) or use node-webkit.

Comment: @barry-johnson thanks for your help. like you said, my general goal is  a desktop app as a frontend with java (kinda) work as backend and send  different URL for the browser to load. I am looking at the java.awt.desktop class, which can invoke the browser from java but it is not embedded in java.

Comment: @barry-johnson because my application is bounded to java, do you know any other mature technology that can be used as a browser and at the meantime, it has a 'bridge' to java?(embedded in java) Thanks!!!

Comment: I don't know of any other good option than JavaFX's webengine. Someone else may have written a browser in Java which you could license or use if OSS. You should probably post this on [this sister site](http://softwarerecs.stackexchange.com/) seeking libraries, tools, etc, is frowned upon on Stackoverflow. If all you want from the front-end is a browser, why does it matter what it is written in? Why not just use C# or other .net language? Just generally I am still having difficulty understanding what you intend to gain by this approach.